# angular2 http post failing silently

Tags: angular, http, rxjs

My front end checks the back end to see if a visitor model exists. This call works using postman (`POST` to `localhost:1337/visitor/exists` with data: `{'email': 'some@email.com'}`). When I try to get my angular2 service to make the same call, it fails silently.

Here is my service:

```js
@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  private myUrl = 'localhost:1337/visitor/exists';

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  checkVisitor(email :string): Observable<boolean> {
    console.log('in myservice, checkvisitor; email: ', email); // this outputs

    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    let body = {'email': email};

    console.log('body, ', body); // this also outputs

    return this.http.post(this.myUrl, JSON.stringify(body), options)
      .map(this.extractData)
      .catch(this.handleError);

  }

 private extractData(res: Response) {
    console.log('in service, extractData; res: ', res); // this does not print
    let body = res.json();
    return body || { };
  }

 private handleError (error: Response | any) {
    console.log('in handleError'); // this does not print
    let errMsg: string;
    if (error instanceof Response) {
      const body = error.json() || '';
      const err = body.error || JSON.stringify(body);
      errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
    } else {
      errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
    }
    console.error(errMsg);
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
  }
}
```

Why can't I get a response from my backend?

I am calling this in my component:

```js
constructor(private myService : MyService){
}
...
checkEmailUniqueness(fieldTouched){
    if(fieldTouched){
      this.myService.checkVisitor(this.visitor.email)
    }
  }
```

Comment: Where are you setting this.raffleBeUrl?

Comment: Can you try adding `http://` to the beginning of your url?

Comment: What is the response you are getting in the network tab of dev tools?

Comment: Nothing... It appears to not be making the call at all.

Comment: Are you subscribing to the `checkVisitor()` method? Where are you using it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Observables are by default "cold" you need to `subscribe` to them in order to "fire" them.

Example:

```
this.myService.checkVisitor(this.visitor.email).subscribe((response)=>{
   console.log(response);
})
```

Comment: Awesome... Now I'm getting a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` error, but I 1/2 expected that. Thanks!

Comment: @Jeff Glad I could help :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try with this way:

```js
 import { Http, Headers, Response, URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';     

@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  private myUrl = 'localhost:1337/visitor/exists';
private globalHeaders: Headers = new Headers();
  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  checkVisitor(email :string): Observable<boolean> {
    console.log('in myservice, checkvisitor; email: ', email); // this outputs


    let body = {'email': email};

    console.log('body, ', body); // this also outputs

    return this.http.post(this.myUrl, JSON.stringify(body), {headers: this.globalHeaders})
      .map(this.extractData)
      .catch(this.handleError);

  }

 private extractData(res: Response) {
    console.log('in service, extractData; res: ', res); // this does not print
    let body = res.json();
    return body || { };
  }

 private handleError (error: Response | any) {
    console.log('in handleError'); // this does not print
    let errMsg: string;
    if (error instanceof Response) {
      const body = error.json() || '';
      const err = body.error || JSON.stringify(body);
      errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
    } else {
      errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
    }
    console.error(errMsg);
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
  }
}
```